# How to disable and grey out ReactSelect component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am rendering a `ReactSelect` component from `'react-select'` as such:

```
                 <ReactSelect
                         className='react-select react-select-top'
                         classNamePrefix='react-select'
                         id='displayLanguage'
                         menuIsOpen={this.state.openMenu}
                         menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                         styles={reactStyles}
                         options={timeOptions}
                         clearable={false}
                         onChange={this.onChange}
                         onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                         value={this.state.selectedOption}
                         onMenuClose={this.handleMenuClose}
                         onMenuOpen={this.handleMenuOpen}
                         aria-labelledby='changeInterfaceLanguageLabel'
                    />
```

I wanted to know if there was any way to disable and grey out the react select dropdown based on a checkbox I had created. Like seen in this image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs, you can pass a prop called isDisabled.
https://react-select.com/props

I'm assuming you have a state managing the checkbox,

```
                    <ReactSelect 
                         className='react-select react-select-top'
                         classNamePrefix='react-select'
                         id='displayLanguage'
                         menuIsOpen={this.state.openMenu}
                         menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                         styles={reactStyles}
                         options={timeOptions}
                         clearable={false}
                         onChange={this.onChange}
                         onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                         value={this.state.selectedOption}
                         onMenuClose={this.handleMenuClose}
                         onMenuOpen={this.handleMenuOpen}
                         aria-labelledby='changeInterfaceLanguageLabel'
                         isDisabled={this.state.isChecked}        //your checkbox state
                    />
```